# String oauth 2 The Resource Owner Password Flow -- username and client-id swapped

Tags: spring, oauth

I try to set up a OAuth 2 server by following the spring sparklr2 example. I modified it to use a database userDetailsService. When I try to exchange a token with password with curl as below:

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=client1&client_secret=123456&grant_type=password&username=user1&password=abc" http://mymachine:8080/oauth/token
```

It failed on loading user findByUsername(), when I look into the code, it uses the client-id(in my case is 'client1') as username. 
call stack is:
DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(String, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) line: 101
DaoAuthenticationProvider(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider).authenticate(Authentication) line: 132 
ProviderManager.authenticate(Authentication) line: 156
ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter.attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 109
ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 211

I tried curl on sparklr2,

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=my-trusted-client&grant_type=password&username=marissa&password=koala" http://mymachine:8080/sparklr2/oauth/token
```

it is the same, 'my-trusted-client' is passed as username. But I have not figured out why it get the token back correctly for sparklr2.

Answer (score 0):

resolved by changing spring-security-oauth2 version from 1.9.5.RELEASE  to 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.